# Cordova online and offline events are not always firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm writing a simple android app using Cordova and encountered some difficulties with network information plugin. Firing "offline" and "online" events is acting weird for me.

At first, I used to add event listeners inside "onDeviceReady" function as it was recommended in some guides I've read.

```
    var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            document.addEventListener("online", function(){alert('online : true') }, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", function(){alert('online : true') }, false);

            // Here, we redirect to the web site.
            var targetUrl = "https://sputnik.geoscan.aero/";
            var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
            bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
            bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
            window.location.replace(targetUrl);
            },

        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        }
};

app.initialize();
```

No events were fired then. So that, I moved listeners to "bind events" function.

```
    var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            document.addEventListener("online", function(){alert('online : true') }, false);
            document.addEventListener("offline", function(){alert('online : true') }, false);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            // Here, we redirect to the web site.
            var targetUrl = "https://sputnik.geoscan.aero/";
            var bkpLink = document.getElementById("bkpLink");
            bkpLink.setAttribute("href", targetUrl);
            bkpLink.text = targetUrl;
            window.location.replace(targetUrl);
            },

        receivedEvent: function(id) {
            var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
            var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
            var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

            listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
        }
};

app.initialize();
```

Now online event rises only at the application startup just before the web page is loaded and never again. Nothing happens when I turn Wi-Fi on and off after. I really can't understand what is going on.

Comment: Because your event calls once only when you start app, then after you haven't set anything which call that function again. Your code is working fine, if you turn off Wi-Fi and then again start the app it will call offline function only.

Comment: And also change alert for offline and online function as respective `alert('Online : true')` and `alert('Offline : true')`

Comment: Thank you. I understood what's going on. But what shall I do if I want those functions to be called each time my phone goes online or offline?

Comment: You have set interval of any fix seconds or minutes to check if your current status is online or offline

Comment: You have to set code something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6Ljaxwkw/).